# Javascript append input to form

Tags: javascript, forms, input, onkeypress

I have this Script:

```
var countBox = 0;

function addInput() {
var breakNode = document.createElement("br");

var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";
input.name = "input_" + countBox.toString();
input.placeholder = "Notes";
input.onkeydown = "tab()";

var container = document.getElementById('container');
container.appendChild(breakNode);
container.appendChild(input);

countBox += 1;
}
```

it should return

```
<input type="text" name="input_0" placeholder="Notes" onkeydown="tab()">
```

but it only returns

```
<input type="text" name="input_0" placeholder="Notes">
```

But the input.onkeydown doesn't work is there a way to create the first element preferably with Javascript so I can dynamically create a new field when the user presses enter??

Comment: The event expects a function, not a string.

Comment: What elclanrs has said + an event handler set by property does not reflect to the attributes.

Comment: @elclanrs the function is designed to create an input element with the attributes of type="text" name="input_0" palceholder="Notes" onkeydown="tab()" but when I tell it to add the onkeydown attribute it doesn't register so how do I add this??

Comment: when you add a listener via javascript to an element, the resultig html won't change - ever worked with jquery? you'll see it.

Comment: @Teemu then how do I add an event handler??

Comment: There seems to be a correct answer below : ). Some [good reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) about events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is `input.onkeydown = tab;`.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b0scgk1e/) that shows it in action.

In Javascript, and Python and many other scripting languages, functions can be passed as arguments or parameters. Here, we are passing the function `tab()` as the value for the `onkeydown` attribute.

Comment: unfortunately when I run that script the whole input dissapears.

Comment: Don't copy the whole thing from Fiddle - just the line of code, `input.onkeydown = tab;`. I needed the whole code to show how it works.

Comment: the problem is if the function for tab hasn't been created then the function fails and the element not created

Comment: Yes, sorry I assumed you already had the function created. You'll need to have it created before you declare your input.

Comment: @Jdoonan if my answer helped you, please mark it as the correct one. It helps both of our reputations on StackOverflow and betters the community.